# Python PID tuning - Parrot Bebop 2 - Target follower - ROS

Tags: ros, pid, python

I'm developing a PID controller for making the drone follow a detected object.

I used as reference these topics:

- [Ttracking-objects-from-camera-pid-controlling-parrot-ar-drone](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/8849/tracking-objects-from-camera-pid-controlling-parrot-ar-drone-2)
- [Tracking-objects-from-camera-pid-controlling-parrot-ar-drone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713594/tracking-objects-from-camera-pid-controlling-parrot-ar-drone-2/34958479#34958479)

I wrote a Python code that interacts with ROS `bebop_autonomy` package.

For the detection, I used [YOLO](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/).

The problem is that I'm not sure if the PID that I wrote is correct and I don't know how to tune the gain parameters. I have read about the theory of PID tuning like [What are good strategies for tuning PID loops?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/167/what-are-good-strategies-for-tuning-pid-loops)

I also know that with an input step you can graph the response and then based on it tune the gains until you obtain the desired characteristics but here I don't know how to do the graphs as the input is a pixel value of the bounding box.

Do you know how should I tune the gain parameters? Also, let me know if how I developed the PID is correct or if there is a better way to do it.

Code:

```
import rospy
from darknet_ros_msgs.msg import BoundingBoxes
from std_msgs.msg import Empty
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

def set_state(input):   #possible states: "pd", "np " person detected, no person
    global state
    state = input
def get_state():
    return(state)

def callback(data):

Cy_center = 340 #x center position of the image
Cz_center = 240 #y center position of the image
Area_id = 640 * 480 * 0.30 # 30% of pixel area (for x)
K_x = 1 #vel_x paramete
sum_error_x = 0
sum_error_y = 0
sum_error_z = 0

#parameters to tune
Kp_fb = 0.2 #proportional gain FORWARD/BACKWARD
Kd_fb = 1.5 #derivative gain FORWARD/BACKWARD
Ki_fb = 1 #integral gain FORWARD/BACKWARD
Kp_lr = 0.2 #proportional gain LEFT/RIGHT
Kd_lr = 1.5 #derivative gain LEFT/RIGHT
Ki_lr = 1 #integral gain LEFT/RIGHT
Kp_ud= 0.2 #proportional gain UP/DOWN
Kd_ud = 1.5 #derivative gain UP/DOWN
Ki_ud = 1 #integral gain UP/DOWN

state = get_state()

pub = rospy.Publisher('bebop/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size = 1)
pub_land = rospy.Publisher('bebop/land', Empty, queue_size = 1)
pub_takeoff = rospy.Publisher('bebop/takeoff', Empty, queue_size = 1)
empty_msg = Empty()
twist = Twist()

if state == "np":
    twist.linear.x = 0; twist.linear.y = 0; twist.linear.z = 0; 
    twist.angular.x = 0; twist.angular.y = 0; twist.angular.z = -0.3;
    pub.publish(twist)
    print("Looking for person")

for box in data.bounding_boxes:

    if box.Class == "person":

        set_state("pd")
        Cy = box.xmin+(box.xmax-box.xmin)/2;
        Cz = box.ymin+(box.ymax-box.ymin)/2;

        Area_ref = ((box.xmax - box.xmin) * (box.ymax - box.ymin))
        error_y = Cy_center - Cy # LEFT/RIGHT
        #error_z = Cz_center - Cz # UP/DOWN
        error_z = Cz_center - box.ymin #so drone will fly higher
        error_x = Area_id - Area_ref #FORWARD/BACKWARD
        vel_y = error_y/320
        if vel_y >= 1:
            vel_y = 1
        elif vel_y <= -1:
            vel_y = -1
        vel_z = error_z/320
        if vel_z >= 1:
            vel_z = 1
        elif vel_z <= -1:
            vel_z = -1
        vel_x = (error_x*K_x)/Area_id
        if vel_x >= 1:
            vel_x = 1
        elif vel_x <= -1:
            vel_x = -1

        #PID X AXES
        sum_error_x = sum_error_x + vel_x
        last_error_x = vel_x
        output_x = Kp_fb * vel_x + Kd_fb * (vel_x - last_error_x) + Ki_fb * sum_error_x

        #PID Y AXES
        sum_error_y = sum_error_y + vel_y
        last_error_y = vel_y
        output_y = Kp_lr * vel_y + Kd_lr * (vel_y - last_error_y) + Ki_lr * sum_error_y

        #PID Z AXES
        sum_error_z = sum_error_z + vel_z
        last_error_z = vel_z
        output_z = Kp_lr * vel_z + Kd_lr * (vel_z - last_error_z) + Ki_lr * sum_error_z 


    #SEND COMMANDS
    twist.linear.x = 0.5*output_x; twist.linear.y = 0.5*output_y; twist.linear.z = 0.5*output_z; 
    twist.angular.x = 0; twist.angular.y = 0; twist.angular.z = 0;
    pub.publish(twist)


    rospy.loginfo(
        "vel_x: {}, vel_y: {}, vel_z: {}, Classe: {}".format(round(output_x,2), round(output_y,2), round(output_z,2), box.Class)
    )

def main():
    set_state("np")
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():

    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(1)
    rospy.Subscriber('/darknet_ros/bounding_boxes', BoundingBoxes , callback )
    set_state("np") #reset state to no person in case detector fails to detect
    rospy.spin() #blocks until ros node is shutdown


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try :
        main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/15076/18870)

Comment: How do I find the FOPDT model of my system and then how do I find the parameters from the step response?  The problem is that I don't know how to apply it in my case because my input is the center of the ideal bounding box + ideal area. How can I graph it for viewing the response of the system?

Comment: Also my error as it is in pixel is then converted in velocity in the PID

Comment: Maybe I could add in the code 3 graphs with the value of centre of the detected bounding box  + area in the time and then from there see how's the response when the detected person is far away from the centre. What do you think? @Benyamin Jafari

Comment: I don't know exactly about that problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #PID X AXES
    sum_error_x = sum_error_x + vel_x
    last_error_x = vel_x
    output_x = Kp_fb * vel_x + Kd_fb * (vel_x - last_error_x) + Ki_fb * sum_error_x

    #PID Y AXES
    sum_error_y = sum_error_y + vel_y
    last_error_y = vel_y
    output_y = Kp_lr * vel_y + Kd_lr * (vel_y - last_error_y) + Ki_lr * sum_error_y

    #PID Z AXES
    sum_error_z = sum_error_z + vel_z
    last_error_z = vel_z
    output_z = Kp_lr * vel_z + Kd_lr * (vel_z - last_error_z) + Ki_lr * sum_error_z
```

Your error for the derivative terms are all wrong. vel_x - last_error_x is always zero because you assign the last error variables as vel variable.